# How to access a property of App() globally (in React App, from pyodide)

Tags: reactjs, pyodide

I have implemented pyodide in a React App [like so](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide/issues/552#issuecomment-765167808).

In `src/App.js` in the example from the link above, let's say I have `someProperty` in `App()` that I want to access from `script.py`.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [output, setOutput] = useState("(loading...)");
  const [someProperty, setSomeProperty] = useState("Initial state");  // this one
  const runScript = code => {
    window.pyodide.loadPackage([]).then(() => {
  ...
```

Under normal circumstances of pyodide, I would use `import js` to access javascript scope from python [like in the docs](https://pyodide.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_pyodide_from_javascript.html#accessing-javascript-scope-from-python).

> The JavaScript scope can be accessed from Python using the js module (see [Using Javascript objects from Python](https://pyodide.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_conversions.html#type-conversions-using-js-obj-from-py)). This module represents the global object window that allows us to directly manipulate the DOM and access global variables and functions from Python.

However, the property is inside `App()`, not directly under `window`.

How would I access `someProperty` inside `App()` from `script.py`?

In other words, where is `App()` located under `window` property? Is it even possible to access properties of `App()` globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create a JS object that has access to those local variables

```js
let my_module = {
  someProperty : function(){
    return someProperty;
  }
};
```

that you can then register as a Python module with,

```js
pyodide.registerJsModule("my_js_module", my_module);
```

so it can then imported as,

```py
from my_js_module import someProperty
```

See the [documentation for more details](https://pyodide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/faq.html#how-do-i-create-custom-python-packages-from-javascript). This will only work with the development version of pyodide or the upcoming 0.17.0 release.